# Dynamic tree building with recursive backtracking

Tags: java, recursion, tree, backtracking

I have this problem that I need to solve a recursive backtracking issue. It looks a lot like the n-queen problem, but is different in the way that it uses different candidates with a a-symmetric board. There are a total of four different candidates that each have dependency's on one and another. I have 2 aces, 2 kings, 2 queens and 2 jacks. Each ace has to be next to (horizontal or vertical) to a king, each king has to be next to a queen and each queen has to be next to a jack and non of the pieces can have duplicates next to them. The board with the right solution looks like this:

```
Grid (y, x)(only the positions between *y,x* are available for candidates): 
4,1 4,2 *4,3* 4,4
3,1 *3,2* *3,3* *3,4*
*2,1* *2,2* *2,3* 2,4
1,1 1,2 *1,3* 1,4

Possible Solution
. . K . 
Q J Q .
. A K A
. . J .
```

Now my problem is that I want to use a tree to keep track of the candidates as parents and children of a tree. I have not yet implemented the tree, but I was wondering if the method as shown in this example is a good way to create a tree from. And if this is a good way to create a tree from, how do I start, how does the tree know to which parent it should at a child and also go back when the solution doesn't fit?

I hope I've added enough information about this situation, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but it doesn´t look like you´ve completely grasped how the recursive search algorithm should work in this case . The tree structure you want to build is typically not explicitly implemented, instead it is the structure of recursive calls that will look like a search tree. If you look at the pseudo-code implementation here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking , you will see that there is no tree structure involved, and the backtracking (done when reject returns true) is done just by returning from the current invocation.

In your case you may want to do the search on a single data structure, instead of copying it, so backtracking means removing the candidate piece you just put down, and then returning.

Comment: I've been working on the solution for a while and I finally found the correct solution! You were right, I miss interpreted the backtracking algorithm about the tree implementation. I implemented it without the tree and it works :) Thanks for letting me think about it in another way ;)